# Domain Records: Should they be added with the registrar, hosting provider, or at app level?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, cname-record, cloudflare, digital-ocean

- I have several domains registered with [GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com).
- I used [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com) to protect against DDOS.
- My apps are hosted on [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com).
- I use [VestaCP](https://vestacp.com/) to manage some of my older apps.

Each of these four services have got the option for setting `A`, `AAAA`, `CNAME`, `MX`, `TXT`, `NS`, `SRV`, `CAA` etc...

**Where should I make these changes to records, or should I be doing it in all four places?**

Excuse the noob question, I've searched the web and can't seem to find any definitive answer. Currently I'm adding records all over the place, but that really doesn't feel right.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: I believe, given that you want to use CloudFlare, that their solution requires you to use their DNS. You do not do it in all four places. You'll have to point the domain at the nameservers of whichever of the four services you pick via GoDaddy's control panel, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks very much- that's really helpful. So now that I've pointed nameservers `NS` to CloudFlare, I should manage everything else on Cloudflare? When I add a subdomain should this be done on CloudFlare, or DigitalOcean, or VestaCP?

Comment: p.s. put it as an answer, and I'll upvote